# Create Menu Border and Increase menu Size

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Inspina theme.i have Created Menu left navigation Menu . now I want add Menu border Line how i can add border line ? i am using  Bootstrap css.here I  added some My Code please  any one help me ? i need to add  border line or every menu

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side md-skin" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
            <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">

                <li class="nav-header">
                    <div class="dropdown profile-element">
                        <span>
                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="~/Images/2.png" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; margin-left: 45px;" />
                        </span>
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                            <span class="clear">
                                <span class="block m-t-xs text-muted text-xs">


                                    <strong class="font-bold" style="font-size: 14px; padding-left: 0px;">@User.Identity.Name<b class="caret"></b></strong>
                                </span>@*<span class="fa arrow"></span>*@ @*<span class="text-muted text-xs block">Art Director <b class="caret"></b></span>*@
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeInRight m-t-xs btn btn-w-m btn-info">
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Profile", "Account")" style="font-size: 16px;">Profile</a></li>
                            @*<li><a href="@Url.Action("Contacts", "AppViews")">Contacts</a></li>*@
                            @*<li><a href="@Url.Action("Inbox", "Mailbox")">Mailbox</a></li>*@
                            @*<li class="divider"></li>*@
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")" style="font-size: 16px;margin-right: 38px;">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo-element">
                        Tick&Tie
                    </div>
                </li>



<li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "Client")">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Client")"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.dashboard" style="font-size:18px">Dashboard</span> @*<span class="fa arrow"></span>*@</a>

                         </li>


                <li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "Projects")">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Projects")">
                        <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>  <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.layouts" style="font-size:18px">Projects</span>

                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "Profile")">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Profile", "Account")">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>  <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.layouts" style="font-size:18px">Profile</span>

                    </a>
                </li>



                <li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "AppViews")">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Contacts2", "AppViews")"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.appviews" style="font-size:18px">Team</span></a>

                </li>
                <thead></thead>
                <td>

                <li class="@Html.IsSelected(controller: "Profile")">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("GoogleMaps", "Miscellaneous")">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.layouts" style="font-size:18px">Contact Us</span>

                    </a>
                </li>
                </td>

            </ul>
        </div>


    </nav>
```

Comment: Please provide working demo or live link where we can see code in action then we can help in better way.

Comment: Short-hand rule: `border: width style colour`, specific rules: `border-top/bottom/left/right: width style colour`,  individual border values: `border-width: value; border-style: value; border-color: value;`. Learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border

Comment: @Leothelion i send theme Live link  http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0R5L90S

Comment: Something like this: `.nav>li {border-bottom: 1px solid white;}`? You need to be a tad more specific.

Comment: thank you @UncaughtTypeError i will try this

Comment: working well thank you

Comment: @thenna_tick Good! You're obviously new here to stackoverflow, I'd recommend brushing up on the basic "do's and don'ts" of the site so that the community can better assist you in future. Questions like these generally won't receive much support and attention without example links and explanations of what you've already tried - otherwise it seems like you're not bothered with actually learning about the issue, you're just hoping someone will toss the right answer your way - kind of like what I've just done. You could spend 10-15 minutes on google and you'd have your answer and learn something.

Comment: thank you @UncaughtTypeError i will learn sure